# Updating a html form using Java

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, jsp

I have a web application which includes some html and jsp files with form-elements inside them. My application has the ability to let users put data into the jsp-files, click a button, and than this data gets saved into a MySQL-database.

What I'm trying to do now is update that same form. I know I can load the old data into the html fields with some simple Java. But I also want to make these fields editable when clicking inside them so a user can change the values of the fields.than press a button and than an Update query gets executed which I will code in Java.

I tried browsing Google for answers, but I can't really find anything. Does anybody know how I can make these fields editable for my users?

Comment: It would help to provide your code/example so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from database to the value of inputs fields after that the user can change these values and when he click on submit button  the new data are passed to the database

you need :

1/  a java class where you connect to database (to load data)

2/ servlet1 that pass data to the jsp

3/ in your jsp you must have a form that call another servlet(servlet2) where you put
`<input type="text" value="${MY-DATA}"/>`

4/ servlet2 that call a method to update data in database